# PDO MYSQL Create table if not exists and find out if it has been created

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a possibility to ask PDO whether a

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

statement actually created a table? I am looking for something similar to check lastInsertID after an INSERT IGNORE statement. If you don't get a result for lastInsertID from PDO, then no data was inserted (because of already existing keys).

Comment: `if(condition is true) { great } else{ not so great }`, *in a nutshell.*

Comment: @funky Forty Niner: Ok thanks, but the question is, where do I get the condition parameter from?

Comment: you would assign a variable to a query and check against it to see if it was was successful and checking for errors on the `else{}` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php. That's what I take from this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner nope, no error is raised in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although mysql's documentation is not great on this, the `if not exists` clause will result in a mysql warning if the table does exist. Unfortunately, PDO only captures mysql errors, not warnings, so you have to execute a `show warnings` sql statement after the `create table` and parse its results to check if any warning has been raised:

```
$warnings = $pdoconn->query("SHOW WARNINGS")->fetchObject();
// example output of $warnings OR NULL
// stdClass Object
// (
//        [Level] => Warning
//        [Code] => 1050
//        [Message] => Table '...' already exists
// )
```

If no warning is raised that the table already exists and there is no other error raised for the `create table` statement, then the table was created as a result of the last `create table`.

To be honest, it may be simpler not to use the `if not exists` clause and then just use the standard pdo exception handling to capture the mysql error if the table exists. The `if not exists` clause was really meant for long sql scripts that do not have proper error handling.

Comment: I'll think I'll go with the PDO exception handling, seems the safest solution for me.